# IntelliJ double quotes identifiers in SQL, during auto-completion

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

Starting from version 15, IntelliJ started putting double quotes around SQL identifiers during auto-completion inside Strings.

I tried changing this at Preferences > Editor > Code Style > SQL and General > Smart Keys, but without success.

Is there an option inside IntelliJ to turn this off?

Comment: We know about it, please watch this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118768

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing SQL dialect from oracle to postgres removed quotes on auto complete.

Right click -> change dialect.